# Someone please explain this javascript

Tags: javascript

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdRJGz

I've tried for a while and it seems that the script is simply not running. I'm sure that I have js enabled , maybe there's a bug i didn't catch?

```
function hello(){
``getElementById("message").style.display="block";
  getElementById("block").style.display="block";
};

function disappear(){
  getElementById("message").style.display="none";
  getElementById("block").style.display="none";
};
```

Comment: The codepen you linked doesn't work because it's missing external files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here let me explain,this hello and disappear r two functions which will trigger when u do an event like button click or something in ur code, message is an id of an element u set in ur page, n ur calling it specifically using its id and ur setting its style. I dont knw how u want ur code to behave but with the given information this is the best assumption i can make.

Answer (score 1):

If you would open up the developer console, you'd see the problem immediately: `getElementById()` is not defined. You're looking for

```
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 1):

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a member of the `Document` object

Correct your code like

```
function hello(){
    document.getElementById("message").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("block").style.display="block";
};

function disappear(){
    document.getElementById("message").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("block").style.display="none";
};
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVRgmW